# how write orderByField query in cakephp 3

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp-3.0

In sql, I have this query, It is working perfectly and order by given array in  "order BY Field". But in cakephp it is not working.

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE users.Id IN (3,7,2,13)
ORDER BY FIELD(users.Id ,3,7,2,13)
```

I get the users in following order. which is perfect

```
user _id
 3
 7
 2
13
```

Cakephp 3

```
 $unique_user_id_list = (3,7,2,13);
 $id_list = '3','7','2','13';      This is string. 

$users = $this->Users->find('all',[
                'contain' => [],           
                'conditions'=>['Id IN' => $unique_user_id_list],
                'order BY FIELD'=>['Users.Id'=>$id_list]
            ]);
```

In this query, I get user in following order

```
user_id
  2 
  3
  7
 13
```

I tried both following ways but no one work.  Only "order" clause gives error while other one "order by field" gives no error but does not work as expected.

```
   'order'=>['Users.Id'=>$id_list]
    'order BY FIELD'=>['Users.Id'=>$id_list]
```

Any idea how to write above sql query in cakephp 3 to get it work.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for this question 
In short words  `'order' => "FIELD(id, '2', '3', '7', '13')"`

In detail first use loop to convert array in string.

```
 $id_list; 

 foreach ($unique_user_id_list as $key => $value) {
                if($check == 1){
                    $id_list = 'FIELD ( Id'.',' . "'". $value. "'";
                    $check =2;
                }
                else{
                    $id_list = $id_list . "," . "'". $value. "'";
                }

            }
            $id_list = $id_list . ")";
```

above loop will generate `"FIELD(id, '2', '3', '7', '13')"`

Full query how I used it is given below.

```
$users = $this->Users->find('all',[
                    'contain' => [],
                    'conditions'=>['Id IN' => $unique_user_id_list],
                    'order'=> $id_list
                ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the order statement as follows

```
->order(['users.Id'=>'ASC']);
```

Comment: i don' want by user id ASC or DESC. actually i need them in specific order given in array. But thanks.